# Node.js socket.io Status line does not end with CRLF

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js, passport.socketio

Everytime socket.io try to connect i got an error (chrome 33 / firefox 24) :

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://playground-c9-doum.c9.io/socket.io/1/websocket/QBGO1ZlPhWUBkMVQ9cUP' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line does not end with CRLF socket.io.js:2371

On server side :

```
var io = socket.listen(server);
var store = require('connect-mongo')(express);

io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport: require('passport'),
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
    key:         'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect     stores its session_id
    secret:      constant.SALT,    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:       new store({
        mongoose_connection: db,
        collection: constant.SESSION_COLLECTION,
    }),
    success:     onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:        onAuthorizeFail,
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat:newText', function (data) {
        console.log(socket.handshake.user);
        data.username = socket.handshake.user.username;
        io.sockets.emit('chat:newText', data);
     });
});
```

client side :

```
var connect = function () {
    if (Auth.isLoggedIn() === true) {
        socket = io.connect();
        connected = true;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Socket wont connect as user is not logged in');
        return false;
    }
};
```

I'm using express, passport, passport-socket.io...

I dont think the problem is from passport-socket.io as i tried removing the 'auth' part of the socket config (io.set('authorization')) but i get the same problem.

I also tried to give a specific url to the client socket.connect(url) but didnt work either.

Socket.io is not failing completly, the websocket connection is abord so it start xhr-polling (a pain...).

Done lot of research and didnt find anything on that problem (also posted a new issue on github).

npm socket.io -v give 1.3.8
/socket.io/socket.io.js (client) is Socket.IO.js build:0.9.16

Comment: How have you configured your client and server regarding transports?

Comment: Not really, as far as i know, transport is set to websocket by default... from the doc

    transports defaults to websocket, htmlfile, xhr-polling, jsonp-polling

What should i do? Remove all other transport?

Comment: No, but it seems that socket.io gives up because websocket is not available and it falls to xhr-polling

Comment: But why is the handshake failling? I do understrand from the error message that one of the header should finish by CLRF but it doesnt... any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: try using full URL in io.connect() part like socket = io.connect('http://host:port')